# Strange error in deploying my AngularJS App on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on an AngularJS App using Parse and Firebase as backend. This app works perfectly in my local system. I'm facing a very strange issue in deploying this App on Parse. The error is as following-

When I try to deploy the console says:

**Deploy failed. Retrying deploy...**

For a few times and then finally returns a very strange error which looks like:

> Uploading source files
>
> multiple errors: WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.12:57594: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. | WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.12:57600: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did  not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond. | WSARecv tcp
>   10.0.0.12:57564: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has  failed to respond. |
>   WSASend tcp 10.0.0.12:57642: An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host. | WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.12:57572: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period  of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond. | WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.12:57629: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond. | WSASend tcp 10
>   .0.0.12:57614: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host. | WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.12:57640: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the r emote host. | WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.12:57645: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. | EOF |
>   parse: error with status=504 and body="" | WSA Send tcp
>   10.0.0.12:57624: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. | WSASend tcp 10.0.0.12:57606: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host. | WSARecv tcp
>   10.0.0.12:57592: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, o r established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. |
>   parse: error with status=504 and body="" | WSARecv tcp
>   10.0.0.12:57602: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a  period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. |
>   parse: error with status=504 and body="" | WSARecv tcp 10.0.0.
>   12:57590: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. |
>   WSASend tcp 10.0.0.12:57654: An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host.

I have followed the Parse deploy guidelines properly and adjusted my folder structure accordingly. Here is how my App folder structure looks like:

> proxbee_V1
>
> ```
> cloud
>
>    main.js
>
> config
>
>    global.json
>
> public
>
>    app
>
>      bower_components
>
>      images
>
>      js
>
>      app.js
>
>      index.html
>
>    node_modules
>
>    bower.json
>
>    package.json
> ```

I tried deploying several times but I'm totally stuck at this point. There is not much information about it as well. Please help me resolve this issue.